# How to command Directional Movement in dronekit?

Tags: dronekit-python

Is any way to execute directional movement (turn left, move forward, etc) for Dronekit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Dronekit for Copter you can use velocity control or target positioning, The dronekit documentation explain it very good in here http://python.dronekit.io/guide/copter/guided_mode.html. But if you want to control Plane you can use Channel Override, basically it work by emulating a remote control, They also explain it in the documentation http://python.dronekit.io/examples/channel_overrides.html.